# Number of solutions for $\sum_{i=1}^{4} x_i < 22$ with condition.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm looking for the number of solutions to  $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{4} x_i < 22$ where $x_i > i$

Any help is appreciated.

I tried solving it using combinations to do $C(11,4)$ but that doesn't seem to be the right answer.

Comment: Just curious, why do you say, "that doesn't seem to be the right answer?" As you have stated the question, $C(11,4)=\binom{11}4$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Ok. I guess the wrong answer is on the teacher's solution sheet. Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible that you have the wrong question? Quite often, people paraphrase questions here, and accidentally omit details. It's certainly possible that the answer sheet is wrong, of course.) As a rule, good idea to post the question exactly as it is in the problem sheet.

Comment: Thanks, just got confirmation that there is a mistake on the solution sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+y=21$,where $y\geq 0$.

$(x_1-2)+(x_2-3)+(x_3-4)+(x_4-5)+y=7$

in which every element is greater than or equal to zero.